# Reading JSON string and find the max value as integer

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

I have a JSON string as follows:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = '{"value": [
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211110"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211110"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211110"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211112"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211112"
    },
    {
        "AEDAT": "20211112"
    }
]}';
```

Now I want to read this JSON in SQL Server using `OPENJSON()` and find the MAX value for each `AEDAT`. For this, I am using the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(value)
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value')
```

The above query is returning a row with key value pair as below:

```
{"AEDAT":"20211112"}
```

My objective is to get only `20211112` as integer.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the max value as integer, you need to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause with columns definitions). This schema depends on the structure of the parsed JSON (in your case it's a JSON array):

```
SELECT MAX(AEDAT) AS MaxAEDAT
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value') WITH (
   AEDAT int '$.AEDAT'   
)
```

If the parsed values are dates, you may try a different statement:

```
SELECT MAX(TRY_CONVERT(date, AEDAT, 112)) AS MaxAEDAT
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value') WITH (
   AEDAT varchar(8) '$.AEDAT'   
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`OPENJSON` without explicit schema, gives you the value column which, in your example, will contain an object such as `{"AEDAT": "20211110"}` having type = 5. Use `JSON_VALUE` on that object:

```
select max(cast(json_value(j.value, '$.AEDAT') as int))
from openjson(@json, '$.value') as j
```